# How "git stash -A" exclude .gitignore content?

Tags: git, gitignore

I add .gitignore.Like this:
prebuilts
out

I use "git stash -A" to stash my modifies,but prebuilts folder,out folder also stash.
I don't want stash my ignore folder,what can I do ?

Comment: `git stash` does not have a `-A` (uppercase A) option, but it does have a `-a` (lowercase `a`) option. But that means `git stash save --all` which means Git should include *all* files, tracked, untracked, or untracked-and-ignored.  If you don't want *all* files, don't use the `--all` option.

Comment: But I want stash some files(new foldler),other folders(prebuilts,out) should be ignored,have a good methods?

Comment: Since I have no idea *why* you want to `git stash` some but not all files, I have no recommendations either. I suspect a language barrier here (English vs Chinese most likely) but I find the intent of your question unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You might not want to use [git stash --all](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), since the doc mentions:

> If the `--all` option is used instead then **the ignored files are stashed and cleaned in addition to the untracked files**.

And if some ignored files are still stashed, make sure they were not already tracked: do a `git status` before the stash: if the out folder has some files currently modified, that means they were added to the index and tracked already (`git add -f` would be able to add a file even if it is declared ignored)

Check also which ignore rule actually does (or does not) apply to any file with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```